# Message order in UML 2.0 sequence diagrams

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, xmi

How the order of the messages is modeled in UML 2.0 sequence diagrams?

I've browsed the [UML 2.2 Superstructure specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.2/) and the only structure I found to model order is the `GeneralOrdering` class. I'm modeling my system with [Papyrus](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/), but it doesn't insert message ordering information automatically, so I miss guidelines on the use of this class.

I had the idea to test other tools and check the XMI output, but those that exported the sequence diagram properly used proprietary extensions to model message order. I tried [Umodel](http://www.altova.com/umodel.html), [astah*](http://astah.change-vision.com/en/index.html), [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/), [PowerDesigner](http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/powerdesigner), [Software Ideas Modeler](http://www.softwareideas.net/) and [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/).

Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question in Eclipse Papyrus's forum, where I got the following answer:

"I'm not sure about the specifics of Papyrus, but in the UML specification, the 'fragments' relationship from Interaction to InteractionFragment is ordered (Figure 14.3), so that determines the order of the messages."

Follow this [link](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=rview&goto=662843#msg_662843) for the full message.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use **Papyrus with the sequence diagram** because it doesn't really work well. It is impossible to create a diagram with this tool. The other tools you mentioned are a lot better. 
After studing all the market tools my conclusions are:

**The best sequence diagram** on the market is RSA IBM.

- The best Class diagram is Omondo EclipseUML.
- The best usecase diagram is RSA and Visual Paragdigm.

By the way the xmi model of the sequence diagram has never been a success and is really a mess. Except the sequence diagram all the other diagrams at really well-done at model/xmi by the OMG specification of UML 2.3.
Really good specification but sequence diagram was and is still a misery !! s

Comment: Thanks for your analysis on the tools, but that's not what I'm after right now. I'm working on a code generation technique that should be tool agnostic, reason why I chose to rely on the XMI specification. I agree with you that Papyrus isn't the best tool, especially when it comes to usability, but it implements the UML 2 specification.

Comment: It does implement a GMF mapper to EMF which then transform the information the UML2. This is not really an XMI but an EMF model hich need to be transformed using GMF. If you just analyze the XMI then this is not UML2 specification !!

Comment: As stated in Papyrus site and based on what I used, it seems to implement the UML2 specification. Didn't get what you tried to say about XMI not being UML2.

Comment: You need to export the sequence diagram from GMF graphical format to XMI using EMF serialization. You can not change something in the diagram and look immediately at the xmi. Except this live change it is the same but really painful to wait, use export and hope it well generated. I have checked the xmi exported format and in many cases it was not correct for Papyrus with the sequence diagram !!

Comment: I'll give a closer look to XMI exported by Papyrus, but so far it seemed correct to me (maybe I'm missing the details, as the one that generated this question :P). About the wait to export the diagram, I believe you are using another version (I'm using 0.8, installed from the milestone update site). It ain't automatic (neither of the other tools were), but it is as quick as a "Save as.." operation.